# Combobox hidden on resize

Tags: c++, c, winapi, combobox

Whenever I resize my controls in my window, in response to a WM_SIZE message, they resize and redraw themselves fine. But my combobox control (a dropdown list) disappears whenever I give it a resize message, until I hover over it to bring it back.

There are two possibilities, either it is not redrawing when I resize it, or it is being hidden by my tab control. So how would I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is probably the tab control hiding your control.

You can use [`SetWindowPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(VS.85).aspx) to set its z-order with specifying `SWP_NOMOVE` and `SWP_NOSIZE`.

You can also use [`BringWindowToTop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632673(VS.85).aspx) to bring the combobox to the top of your z-order.